# Symfony propel criterion inside for loop

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

```
$record_values = new Criteria();
$record_values->add(TblfieldsPeer::CUSTOMER_ID, $company_qu_id);
$record_values->add(TblfieldsPeer::RECORD_TYPE_ID, $query_rtype);
for($fieldid_arrayCount=0;$fieldid_arrayCount<count($fieldIds);$fieldid_arrayCount++)
{
$currentFieldId = $fieldIds[$fieldid_arrayCount];
if(isset($query_values[$fieldid_arrayCount]))
{
$criterion1 = $record_values->getNewCriterion(TblfieldsPeer::FIELDS_ID, $currentFieldId);
$criterion1->addAnd($record_values->getNewCriterion(TblfieldsPeer::FIELD_VALUES, $query_values[$fieldid_arrayCount]));
$record_values->add($criterion1);
}
}
$record_values_results = TblfieldsPeer::doSelect($record_values, $con1);
```

But only last criterion is added. I check the databases in debug toolbar only the last criterion is there. What could be the problem.
Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a propel expert but maybe you could try to use 2 alternative changes:

- to use `addAnd` statement instead of `add` one in `$record_values->add($criterion1)`
- to put `$record_values->add($criterion1)`  outside the (of course after) cycle changing `$criterion1` in a field outer the cycle and using only the `addAnd` statement for `$criterion1`